# What is google bot guard anti spam?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, security

I am working on a wordpress website that has been developed by someone else. The website faced serious problems during last few days. After I inspected the Http requests in the developer tools found lots of strange javascript files being requested from other hosts. The strangest requests are those which are hosted on `google.com` as you can see in the image below:

[image]

The first line of the response is a comment which says "If you are interested contact this base64 encoded string", which after decoding the string it is this email address: `botguard-contact@google.com`. Does anyone knows what is this script and if it is not from google, how it is hosted on `google.com`?

Comment: https://www.quora.com/How-does-Googles-Botguard-work

Comment: @rocky I think that is the only information about this script in the internet, also I am not sure If I understood what is it :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This script is a component of [Google reCAPTCHA](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html), an anti-spam tool. It is probably being used on a comment or contact form on your site.